# How do I make this loop recursive?

Tags: shell

I am trying to loop recursively in all sub directories to process $i.
This is all I have, any suggestions would be helpful!

```
for i in *.mov; 
do
 ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4";
Rm "$i" ;
 done
```

Comment: it is dangerous to do `rm` without testing that `ffmpeg` succeeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a GNU or similar userland, a way to process multiple files at the same time to speed things up:

```sh
find . -name "*.mov" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P4 sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" "${1%.*}.mp4" && rm "$1"' sh
```

Replace the 4 in `-P4` with the number of conversions to run in parallel (which depends on how many cpu cores you have available).

Or to only process one file at a time, any `find`:

```sh
find . -name "*.mov"  -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" "${1%.*}.mp4" && rm "$1"' sh \{\} \;
```

Comment: Now how would I make this search for multiple file types, .mov,.avi.mp4.. etc?

Comment: @PeterMarkFriedladner `-name "*.mov" -o -name "*.avi"` etc.

Comment: Outputs, 'find: *.MOV: unknown primary or operator.